# Is there any independent significance to OEIS sequence A160649?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the sequence whose first term is 2, and whose subsequent term in each case is the sum of the previous term plus the sum of the exponents in the prime factorization of the previous term. Does this sequence count or describe anything of independent interest? This is sequence A160649 of OEIS. The article for this sequence in OEIS is Spartan, giving no commentary on its significance. A google search does not seem to reveal any significance either. So, the question is: Is there any independent (perhaps real-world) significance to OEIS sequence A160649?

Comment: This is a rather artifical construction, We can safely assume that it has no independent meaning, not alone a "real-world meaning".

Comment: @Peter: “A failure of imagination does not constitute an insight into necessity.”
-- Patrick Barrow

Comment: @Peter: primes multiplied by 4 seems artificial, too, but has a real-world application: https://oeis.org/search?q=12%2C+20%2C+28%2C+44%2C+52%2C+68%2C+76%2C+92%2C+116&language=english&go=Search

Comment: So, what have we here – a confederacy of dunces?